# COUNTIFS for Single Column Range but using Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet of 25k plus telephone records.  The sheet has the phone numbers broken down so I have a single column (Column L) that has all the area codes dialed.  I am trying to search that column for all the area codes from a single state which are listed in another column (Column O).  I have tried a couple of COUNTIFS based on web searches but all simply return 1 as the count instead of an expected 12,689.

I tried the following:
=COUNTIFS(L2:L25676,O2:O24)     The first range is the range of area codes, second is range of state area codes.

I also tried:
=COUNTIFS(L2:L25676,{"239","305","321","324","352","386","407","448","561","645","656","689","727","728","754","772","786","813","850","863","904","941","954"})

And this":
=SUM(COUNTIFS(L2:L25676,{"239","305","321","324","352","386","407","448","561","645","656","689","727","728","754","772","786","813","850","863","904","941","954"}))

Any and all advise is greatly appreciated.  I am certain at this point I am misusing the COUNTIFS function.

Comment: Welcome! Please try `=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(L2:L,O2:O)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `filter(match())` pattern, like this:

`=counta( iferror( filter(L2:L, match(L2:L, O2:O, 0)) ) )`